# mv: cannot stat error : No such file or directory error

Tags: linux, bash, stat

I need to move the files of a directory to another directory.I get stat error when I used the following program.

```
for i in dir1/*.txt_dir; do
mv $i/*.txt  dir2/`basename $i`.txt
done
```

error message

```
mv: cannot stat `dir1/aa7.txt_dir/*.txt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems self-explanatory. There are no `*.txt` files in `dir1/aa7.txt_dir`.

Answer (score 7):

Normally, when a glob which does not match any filenames is expanded, it remains unchanged. Thus, you get results like this:

$ rm *.bak
 rm: cannot remove `*.bak': No such file or directory

To avoid this we need to change the default value of nullglob variable.

```
    #BASH

    shopt -s nullglob

    for i in dir1/*.txt_dir; do
       mv $i/*.txt  dir2/'basename $i'.txt
    done
```

Read more about it here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

```
mv $i/*.txt  dir2/`basename $i`.txt
```

This doesn't work when there are no text files in `$i/`. The shell passes the raw string `"$i/*.txt"` to `mv` with the unexpanded `*` in it, which `mv` chokes on.

Try something like this:

```
for i in dir1/*.txt_dir; do
    find $i -name '*.txt' -exec mv {} dir2/`basename $i`.txt \;
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually there are text files in $i/. But still same error.

Answer (score 0):

when you put directory/* alone in for iteration, it list each file with absolute path.  use `ls

for i in `ls dir1/*.txt_dir` ; do

Answer (score -1):

Whilst it is not shown in your example - using the correct quotes is important.
in BASH "*" evaluates to * and '*' evaluates to the expansion glob.
so

```
`ls *`
```

will show all files in directory and

```
`ls "*"`
```

will show all files named the literal *