# Why Error while moving a file from the directory1 to a directory2 in linux?

Tags: linux, command, move

Getting an error like this while moving one file from one directory to another directory inside it:

> mv: cannot stat '/Home/Documents/liza_susan/org_chart.html': No such
>   file or directory

My linux command is:

```
 mv /Home/Documents/liza_susan/org_chart.html Home/Documents/liza_susan/task
```

But the error is showing no such file or directory

[image: LooK A]

see this image.. I want to move this ***org_chart.html*** file from ***liza_susan*** directory to task directory in ***liza_susan*** directory

Comment: In Linux file and directory names are case sensitive. Try `/home`instead of `/Home`. Check the names of the other directories and of the file, too.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: see the updated question.. i have uploaded an image

Comment: Use a terminal and shell commands, including `pwd`, `ls`, `stat`, `mv`. Be aware of [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) so see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Your home directory is probably not `/Home` but something like `/home/liza`. Try `echo ~` and `echo $HOME` to find out

Comment: Please let us Google that for you... [mv: cannot stat No such file or directory in shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77007/56041), [File exists but mv errors out with: “mv: cannot stat ‘file.tar.gz’: No such file or directory”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222793/56041), [mv: cannot stat with *](https://askubuntu.com/q/164497), [mv: cannot stat error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34091346/608639), [mv: cannot stat error : No such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12729784/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that `/Home/Documents/liza_susan/org_chart.html` does not exist. Are you sure the path is correct?

A couple of guesses:

- `/home/*USERNAME_HERE*/Documents/liza_susan/org_chart.html`, or
- `/home/liza_susan/Documents/org_chart.html`
- `~/liza_susan/Documents/org_chart.html`

---

## Update

Do this:

1. `cd ~`
2. `pwd`
3. Use this for your `mv` command (making sure you take care about case-sensitivity`)

---

## Update 2

You can do this to avoid the `/home` trouble

1. `cd ~`
2. `mv Documents/liza_susan/org_chart.html Documents/liza_susan/task`

or even

1. `cd ~/Documents/liza_susan`
2. `mv org_chart.html task`

Comment: What do you see when you do `ls -la /Home/Documents/`?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/Home/Documents/': No such file or directory

Comment: The thing is that because the file browser shows "Home" as the left most word it doesn't mean it's "/Home"

Comment: @liza Please try `cd ~; pwd` to find your home folder

Comment: Than your command is `mv /home/stunntech/Documents/liza_susan/org_chart.html   /home/stunntech/Documents/liza_susan/task`

Comment: mv: cannot stat '/home/stunntech/Documents/liza_susan/org_chart.html': No such file or directory

Comment: what files do you see if you do `cd ~` and then `ls -la`. Is there a `Documents` folder there?

Comment: What can you see when you do `ls -al /home`

Comment: What about `cd ~`, `cd Documents`, `ls -al`? Is there `liza_susan` folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178579/discussion-between-tymtam-and-liza).